# What is a "yield" statement in a function?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Python yield keyword explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Can someone explain to me what the yield statement actually does in this bit of code here:

```
 def fibonacci():
     a, b = 0, 1
     while True:
         yield a
         a, b = b, a+b
```

for number in `fibonacci()`:  # Use the generator as an iterator; print number

What I understand so far is, we are defining a function `finonacci()`, with no parameters?
inside the function we are defining `a` and `b` equal to 0 and 1, next, while this is true, we are yielding `a`. What is this actually doing? Furthermore, while yielding `a`? `a` is now equal to `b`, while `b` is now equal to `a + b`.

Next question, for number in `fibonacci()`, does this mean for every number in the function or what? I'm equally stumped on what yield and 'for number' are actually doing. Obviously I am aware that it means for every number in `fibonacci()` print number. Am I actually defining number without knowing it?

Thanks, sorry if I'm not clear. BTW, it's for project Euler, if I knew how to program well this would be a breeze but I'm trying to learn this on the fly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `yield` makes the function a generator. 
The generator will continue to yield the `a` variable on each loop, waiting until the generator's `next()` method is called to continue on to the next loop iteration.

Or, until you `return` or `StopIteration` is raised.

Slightly modified to show use of `StopIteration`:

```
>>> def fib():
...     a = 0
...     b = 1
...     while True:
...         yield a
...         a = b
...         b += a
...         if a > 100:
...             raise StopIteration
...
>>>
>>> for value in fib():
...     print value
...
0
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
>>>

>>> # assign the resulting object to 'generator'
>>> generator = fib()
>>> generator.next()
0
>>> generator.next()
1
>>> for value in generator:
...     print value
...
2
4
8
16
32
64
>>>
```

Comment: There is no need to `raise StopIteration` inside a generator - just `return`.

Answer (score 4):

When the code calls `fibonacci` a special generator object is created. Please note, that no code gets executed - only a generator object is returned. When you are later calling its `next` method, the function executes until it encounters a `yield` statement. The object that is supplied to `yield` is returned. When you call `next` method again the function executes again until it encounters a `yield`. When there are no more `yield` statements and the end of function is reached, a `StopIteration` exception is raised.

Please note that the objects inside the function are preserved between the calls to `next`. It means, when the code continues execution on the next loop, all the objects that were in the scope from which `yield` was called have their values from the point where a previous `next` call returned.

The cool thing about generators is that they allow convenient iteration with `for` loops.
The for loop obtains a generator from the result of `fibonacci` call and then executes the loop retrieving elements using `next` method of generatior object until `StopIteration` exception is encountered.

Comment: Calling `fibonacci()` again will create a new generator.

Comment: What do you mean return a immediately, it holds the value a for the next loop?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks, I tried to write a very simple explanation, but wrote something completely invalid and embarrassing. Corrected the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Generators have a special property of being iterables which do not consume memories for their values.

They do this by calculating the new value, when it is required while being iterated.

i.e.

```
def f():
    a = 2
    yield a
    a += 1

for ele in f():
    print ele
```

would print

```
 2
```

So you are using a function as an iterable that keeps returning values. 
This is especially useful when you require heavy memory usage, and so you cannot afford the use of a list comprehension

i.e.

```
li = [ele*10 for ele in range(10)]
```

takes 10 memory spaces for ints as a list

but if you simple want to iterate over it, not access it individually

it would be very memory efficient to instead use

```
def f():
    i=0
    while i<10
        yield i*10
        i += 1
```

which would use 1 memory space as i keeps being reused

a short cut for this is

```
ge = (i*10 for i in range(10))
```

you can do any of the following

```
for ele in f():

for ele in li:

for ele in ge:
```

to obtain equivalent results

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1614219) is a great explanation of the `yield` statement, and also of iterators and generators.

Specifically here, the first call to `fibonaci()` will initialize `a` to 0, `b` to 1, enter the while loop and return `a`.
Any next call will start after the `yield` statement, affect `b` to `a`, `a+b` to `b`, and then go to the next iteration of the `while` statement, reach again the `yield` statement, and return `a` again.

Comment: So up until the yield statement, everything before it is just laying down the initial values? Then after the statement, it just executes a, b = b, a+b

Comment: The first statement a, b = 0, 1 is indeed for initialization purpose. It is only executed on the first call to `fibonaci()`.